# Logfile showing empty fields in the server side

Tags: android, logfile

i got a problem with my web services code. with the code I am passing the user credentials to server, but at the server side log file showing empty fields I cant understand the problem as I am new to webservices. I am  using ksoap ,wsdl for my webservices

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

this is the code

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/RegisterUser";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "RegisterUser";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
private static final String URL = "http://........";
private static final String TAG = "HELLO";

Thread t;
ProgressDialog dialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);

    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait while connecting...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
Button regmalebtn;

public void register() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");

SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    // String response1 = request.getProperty(0).toString() ;
    request.addProperty("fname", "raghav");
    request.addProperty("lname", "raju");
    request.addProperty("dateofbirth", "18-01-1985");
    request.addProperty("email", "raghuraju90@yahoo.com");
    request.addProperty("password", "1234");
    //request.addProperty("password", repassword);
    request.addProperty("mobno", "8553456260");
    request.addProperty("latitude", "76");
    request.addProperty("longitude", "82");
    request.addProperty("device_id", "123456");
    request.addProperty("gender", "male");
    // request.addProperty("latitude',latitude);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        androidHttpTransport
                .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        // SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
        String resultData;
        resultData = request.getProperty(0).toString();
    }
    return null;
}
} catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should get a copy of Charles - http://www.charlesproxy.com/

You can configure it to act as a reverse proxy and then if you aim your web service code at the reverse proxy you'll be able to inspect the traffic flowing from your phone to the server. I've outlined the whole process in another thread.

[Android to Drupal cookie transfer Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241085/android-to-drupal-cookie-transfer-q2/6244558#6244558)

If you need help let me know.

Comment: thanks ,as i was getting -1 as my log cat message. Therefore I discussed with my web service provider and came to know that the log files are empty,  help me to get a response like 1 in the log-cat  what should i do? in order to connect and post the data in the server

Comment: How can we solve this  with the help of Ksoap,wsdl and Sax parsing? any Idea?

Comment: Well if your log files are truly empty then it sounds like you may not even be sending out requests... or maybe you are but you need to find that out first. Honestly I've never used HTTPTransportSE before so I'm not sure of the ins and out of using it. But I think you just need to break what you're doing down into steps. The first step I'd use is to grab Charles, set it up as a reverse proxy and then run some super simple web service code like:    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); url.openStream();

Comment: If you can do that and you can see the conversation taking place between your phone and google then run your code and see if anything is coming out of the phone. Once you've done that you can use Charles to inspect the stuff coming out of your phone and make sure it's formatted correctly for your web service.